# Angularjs detect directives on new Dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

Hi i have been working on angular app .My doubt is whether angularjs detects directive when a new DOM is added.

Lets assume this scenario that i have Angular directive named **mention** which compiles when Dom has a class named **mention**

when a new Dom is added with class `<a class="mention">Hello</a>`mention. Does angular directive detects this DOM.

If not how to bind an event on this new DOM.  Consider following scenario.

```js
var app = angular.module('app')
app.controller('Home',function ($scope, $timeout){
  $timeout( function () {
    $(".main").append("<a class='mention'> </a>"));
    }, 5000);
app.directive('mention', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attb) {

    },
    template: '<h1> AT mentions </h1>'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" class='main' ng-controller="Home">
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes, angular uses a `$digest` cycle to see new DOM nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular does not know that new DOM was added and does not invoke directives on these DOM elements. In order to make angular familiar to new DOM, you should compile it as a new template. Here is how your code should look like:

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', []).
  controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout, $compile) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $(".main").append(
        $compile("<a class='mention'>some text</a>")($scope)
      );
    }, 500);
  }).
  directive('mention', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AEC',
      transclude: true,
      link: function (scope, element, attb) {

      },
      template: '<h1> AT mentions <ng-transclude></ng-transclude></h1>'
    }
  });
```

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q4Th2XU52MbOp6vRrjAs?p=preview

You can bind events to new DOM as usual:

```
$(".main").append(
    $compile("<a class='mention'>some text</a>")($scope)
).on('click', function() {
    $window.alert('click')
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/F9esG9YTRF2B25IP1alg?p=preview

Besides of it, you have multiple issues in the code you provided:

- `var app = angular.module('app')` should be `var app = angular.module('app',[])` to declare new module instead of fetching it;
- you placed extra closing parenthesis in the line that adds a new DOM with jQuery
- you should define new directive outside of controller's code
- directives with `transclude:true` should have `<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>` in the template

**Note**

Manipulating DOM directly in Angular is a bad practice. Do it only in directive's `link` or `compile` function or when you have no other choice (e.g. third party code that can't be modified should be integrated with Angular).

Answer (score -2):

To answer this: **YES**. Angular loops over your `DOM elements` at every `$digest` cycle, so if a new node will be created that has a directive appended to it, that directive will indeed be seen by `angular` and initialised.

Revising your code this all seems to have something to do with `$`, which goes outside the `angular scope`. Have you tried wrapping your `append` in an `$apply` like so

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $(".main").append("<a class='mention'> </a>");
}
```

Comment: But my directive function is not working . its not binded to the new DOM

Comment: Are you telling ```angular``` that your directive is a ```class```. You should post the directive code as well so we can take a look at that

Comment: Please check the above scenario .

Comment: now its been added using $timeout, which has angular scope.

Comment: @DanMoldovan Unfortunately, you are wrong in both points: Angular does NOT loop over DOM elements every `$digest` cycle, it traverses `$scope` tree to detect the changes. Angular runs `$digest` cycle after every execution of `$timeout`, therefore wrapping the code that runs inside `$timeout` into `$scope.$apply` has no effect.